# How to avoid double underscores in Rails 5 nested resource namespaced routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

We have some nested resource/namespace routes that worked before upgrading to Rails 5 as is, but now with Rails 5 the routes are complaining about not having an explicit `as:` on the route to name the route/path helper.

Here is an example of our route nesting:

```
resources :categories, path: "schools", only: [:index, :show, :create] do
  namespace :categories, path: "", as: nil do
    resource :increment, only: [:new]
    namespace :admin, path: "admin" do
      resource :dashboard, only: [:show]
    end
  end
end
```

Before the rails 5 upgrade this would produce route helpers like:

**category_admin_dashboard_path**   GET /schools/:category_id/admin/dashboard(.:format) categories/admin/dashboards#show

After the Rails 5 upgrade this is now producing route helpers like:

**categories__category_admin_dashboard_path**   GET /schools/:category_id/admin/dashboard(.:format) categories/admin/dashboards#show

We have tried un-nesting the routes with no luck...I'm sure we are doing something wrong or unconventional.

Can someone offer advice on how to correct this poor nesting of Rails routes?

Comment: Is the “do” at the end of the `resource :increment` line missing in your code as well as the example? Or is it a paste error?

Comment: What's `namespace :categories, path: "", as: nil do` for? It seems useless to me

Comment: Looks like a copy/paste error.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `namespace :categories` with `scope module: :categories`

```
resources :categories, path: "schools", only: [:index, :show, :create] do
  scope module: :categories do
    resource :increment, only: [:new]
    namespace :admin, path: "admin" do
      resource :dashboard, only: [:show]
    end
  end
end
```